# Can donors store their card details on dashboard?

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, iats, payment, user-dashboard

I would like to give access to our donors to the contact dashboard and also let them donate from that page to different campaign or events signup,  so they would not have to enter their details over and over again.

I was also thinking, what if it would be possible to give option to store their credit card details like modern checkout does, for them to avoid entering them every time?

What are possibilities of achieving this? What can go wrong along the way? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to achieve this with a modern token based payment processor like the iATS Payments extension which we wrote the code for. One example of such card-on-file feature already exist:

A process button in the recurring series screen -> this lets admins charge a one time amount to a card-on-file. This could be for e.g. a catch up transaction, an additional year end donation (phone bank calls donor and gets ok to use the card on file) or for a purchase at a silent auction (where to speed up checkout credit cards or bank accounts (ACH EFT or e-cheque) were processed and tokenized ahead of the event).

So a use my card on file does not yet exist for a donor to select as a payment method - it’s definitively possible to put that together.

Comment: Just to clarify - the card info itself is stored at the *payment provider* not in CiviCRM, right? That's what "token based" means here?

Comment: That’s Great!! Since we are in UK and from September we have to be PSD2 compliant. Currently we use paypal pro and it looks like we have to move from paypal. We have considered stripe and I have seen a MIH is already going on. Not sure if Stripe can support card-on-file feature!  Is iATS PSD2 compliance? What sort of work required on this extension to make these 2 features available? If there’s some cost involved what that would be? Thanks

Comment: Yes card on file as card details are relayed to iATS Payments (and stored there) - in return we get a token - fhis is stored in CiviCRM and we can transact on that token - that’s how recurring contributions are initiated and how one time payments can be transacted as well

Comment: I’ve asked our contacts at iATS Payments to let us know what needs to be done re PSD2 compliance (and explain the details to us) our extension is funded (code and support) by iATSPayments and iATS has been great to let us drive/add new features (like the process button or the new reconciliation report templates) are based on feedback by organizations using CiviCRM to handle payments.

Comment: Tapash - we have a client that has 'card on file' working through some custom stuff using React which they built. They asked us to investigate getting off the React code in which case the 'card on file' would need to be in the Stripe extension. If they are interested in going ahead I will contact you to see if your client can contribute

Comment: Thanks @KarinG-SemperIT . That’s quiet supportive of iATS I must say. It would be really good if iATS is able to implement PSD2. Specially for EU civicrm users. At the moment we are in a process to find an alternative to paypal. It could be  stripe or iATS. I would like suggest few things after I try out iATS. If ok, please share your contact details or pls email me at t.datta at live dot com. Thanks

Comment: You can give iATS a try with test credentials TEST88 / TEST88 - feel free to report your findings / suggestions in our queue on GitHub: https://github.com/iATSPayments/com.iatspayments.civicrm